# Appium error packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator, appium, adb

I'm currently learning how to use Appium.

My workspace looks as following:

- I'm using Windows 10 Pro
- Android Studio 3.6.1 as my IDE
- The AVD-Manager from Android Studio
- Adb as a Bridge
- Desktop-Appium 1.15
- And Java jdk-14

After quite some time I got everything to work. I think my PATH variables are set correctly, I can call Java and adb in cmd.

So I wanted to start some test cases, where I want to automate the login of a mail app.

Here I run into the error.

```
#
# Log Appium Server
#
[UiAutomator2] Unable to remove port forward 'Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\Yggdrasil\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8200' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb.exe: error: listener 'tcp:8200' not found'; Code: '1''
[UiAutomator2] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Yggdrasil\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Yggdrasil\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Yggdrasil\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy'
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1585093850179 (00:50:50 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Command 'java -jar C:\\Users\\Yggdrasil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\appium_apk_tools.jar printLaunchActivity C:\\Users\\Yggdrasil\\Downloads\\gmx-6.5.7.apk C:\\Users\\YGGDRA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\de.gmx.mobile.android.mail' exited with code 1; StdErr: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
[MJSONWP]   at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2489)
[MJSONWP]   at io.appium.apktools.StringsXML.silenceLogger(StringsXML.java:120)
[MJSONWP]   at io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:25)
[MJSONWP] 
[MJSONWP]     at ADB.packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest (C:\Users\Yggdrasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\android-manifest.js:136:9)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 1350 ms - 844
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {}
[HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session 404 3 ms - 57
[HTTP]
```

Here are the Appium Desired Capabilities:

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "deviceName": "Android Emulator",
  "appPackage": "de.gmx.mobile.android.mail",
  "appWaitActivity": "com.unitedinternet.portal.ui.login.LoginActivity",
  "app": "C:\\Users\\Yggdrasil\\Downloads\\gmx-6.5.7.apk"
}
```

I googled about Error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest but didn't found a way to solve this for me. Hit me up if you need any more information! Thank you for your time. I greatly appreciate your help!

NOTE:
Instead of `adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'"` I have to use `adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mObscuringWindow'"` to get the appPackage for [Appium Desired Capabilities](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md)

- Is this from the new Version of adb or AVD?

Comment: have you tried to reinstall your appium? looks like something wrong with the package

Comment: I tried it after your comment. It doesn't change a thing. I will try to install Jdk-8 now instead of Jdk-14. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: the 'adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mObscuringWindow'"' comes from the new version of android. Older android versions like 7.0.0 will use the known adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'". Downgrading the android version however doesn't solve the issues

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.

Apparently Appium and Android Studio 3.6 don't go together very well.

Appium is using the SDK tools, you had to edit to the PATH viable. But Android Studio 3.6 is using a new version of SDK tools, so Appium wasn't able to find them properly.

I found this mistake with AppiumDoctor.

After Downgrading Android Studio to version 3.3 all works properly.